# PHP - Auto share using Facebook SDK

Tags: php, facebook

I would like to call the `shareFB()` method to auto share something on a **Facebook Page** which I manage. And maybe pass it data `shareFB($link, $message)`

Currently getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)`.

How can I set this up to work?

```
public function shareFB() {
 require_once( ''.dirname(__DIR__).'/includes/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

try {

  $response = (new FacebookRequest(
  $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
            'link' => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2FETG7tCF0',
            'message' => 'The Sun Full HD 1080p, Amazing Documentary'
                )
            ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

            echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');

        } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

            echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
            echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

        }
}
```

EDIT ***

```
    require_once 'Db.class.php';
    require_once( ''.dirname(__DIR__).'/includes/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

  $app_id = 'xxx'; //Facebook App ID
  $app_secret = 'xxx'; //Facebook App Secret
  $redirect_url = 'http://example.com/com/login'; //FB redirects to this page with a code

  //initialize Facebook
  FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_secret);
  $helper = new FAcebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);

  try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
    die(" Error : " . $ex->getMessage());
  } catch(\Exception $ex) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    die(" Error : " . $ex->getMessage());
  }

    class HelperClass {

    public function shareFB() {
                try {

                    $response = (new FacebookRequest(
                        $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
                            'link' => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2FETG7tCF0',
                            'message' => 'The Sun Full HD 1080p, Amazing Documentary'
                        )
                    ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

                    echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');

                } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

                    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
                    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

                }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `use Facebook\FacebookRequest;` cannot be run within a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
require_once(dirname(__DIR__) . '/includes/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

public function shareFB() {
...
```

For posting to a page, you need `publish_pages` and `manage_pages` and you need to use a Page Token to post "as Page". But that´s not the problem in this case - it only may be a problem after you fixed the problem at hand, so i added it just in case ;)

About using the PHP SDK in general:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-4-0-tutorial/

A lot of stuff is missing from your code. You need to authorize with the correct permissions (see above) and you need to generate a Page Token. Make sure you know about all that stuff.

Here are some additional links about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Thank you. I just did what you suggested and I got past that error. But now i'm getting an undefined $session. I use Facebook login and I already have it set up. Do I create another FB session in the helper class? Or should I try to use my existing one?

Comment: well, you did not create any session yet. i will include some links to tutorials and example code.

Comment: please see my edit. I do all that already in a global.inc.php file. Which I use in regular pages. But I just don't know how to use or include that code in this class. I wouldn't want to write something twice.

Comment: well, in that case you need to debug your session.

Comment: btw, try without that helper class, just put the code outside

Comment: I think I can get it to work outside. But I want it to run when someone posts an item on the website.

Comment: no ... ignore my last comment. I think I know how to do it. I ll just put the code outside and not use the helper class :))

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

> The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be block scoped.

Move the `use` declaration outside of your `shareFB` function.